# Detecting overflow into margins of a compiled pdf

Tags: margins

I have a fairly large pdf file compiled in Tex. I used XeTex to compile, though it doesn't matter for this question I think. 
I want to see if on any page of the PDF, any line, there is text overflowing into the margins. All pages should have a fixed margin of say 1in on the right. Is there a simple way to do this?
Note: The question is not on how to fix an overflow, it is to find *if* is there is an overflow.

Comment: Log file analysis, perhaps?

Comment: @PauloCereda am sorry, how?

Comment: In case of overflow, the .log file messages  like `\overful\hbox at line…`. Furthermore, the number of `bad boxes`(whether vertical or horizontal) is specified at the end oof the log file.  Last tools: the `showframe` package, or the `showframe` option of `geometry` (a frame  of the text area is drawnn on each page)  yields a visual tools to check potential overflows.

Comment: @bissi: the log file contains a lot of hints on how the engine shipped each page, as @Bernard mentioned, so it might be a start on how to detect overflow. `:)`

Comment: @Bernard  the showframe package with geometry does it very well! Although I have to see all pages of the PDF manually. The hbox thing - I do have plenty of them in my log but I am not very sure how to use that. The question is complete, if you give an answer I can accept it

Comment: `\overfullrule=5pt`?

Comment: @bissi: I don't think it's worth an answer. The `\overfullhbox` es may come from something else than an overflow into the margins: it may be the contents of a tabular cell, for instance. What you should do is checking what happens in each case (you have the line number at which this happens, so you can easily swap from the source-code to the resulting place in the .pdf and back).

Comment: If you have overfull hboxes, you cannot be sure if they reeally stick into the margin, of if something in a tabular is too wide. If you have *no* overfull boxes, you can be sure that nothing is sticking over its boundardy anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

The usual classes take a `draft` option whereby any overlong line (or other typeset material) is marked by a black box in the margin.

```
\documentclass[...,draft,...]%
 % {memoir} % or
 % {book} % or
 {report} % or
 % {article}
 % or others
```

The classes can also take a `final` option which does not mark overfull lines (this is a default option so there is no need to actually declare it).